# How to do Google Analytics conversion/event tracking from organic keywords?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, goal-tracking, event-tracking

I'm not using Adwords campaigns.

I'm currently using Google Analytics event tracking to record conversion action upon clicking on the submit button.

I can see `full referrer` stats by selecting `secondary dimension` under `Behavior > Events > Top Events`.  It shows me there the conversion coming from exactly which referrer page.

However, I'm seeing `google` generating most of the conversions in the `full referrer` column.

I do have `Search Console` activated and getting organic search query stats, but that doesn't give me any useful information about user behavior other than my CTR and SERP position stats.

How can I further analyze which organic search queries are generating the conversions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google makes this a bit cumbersome, but you can see the volume that each search query drove to a specific landing page within Search Console.

Go to Search Traffic > Search Analytics, drill down into a specific keyword, then click the "Pages" radio button above the graph. You'll then be able to see what pages absorbed what amount of search traffic.

To tie this to ROI, do a landing page drilldown under the Behavior > Site Content section of GA. If you look at the same page on the same date that you have set in Search Console and set your segment to just organic search traffic, you can look at revenue generated on that day, divide it by organic search sessions, and get a per-session value. This value is super useful for making business decisions (like a mini LTV).