# How can I see how many transactions each search query came from Google organic search?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, google-analytics-4

I have a website which has GA4, GSC, and BigQuery connected to it.

The site is ranking for a bunch of different search queries in Google. I want to know which queries bring me transactions. That is, for which search queries users find my site and make transactions, and for which they do not.

Example: There is a page on car sales. I want to know how many transactions were from users who came to my site by using the search query "buy a car", and how many transactions were made by users who used the search query "yellow car". And so for all the search queries that are for this page.

I need this for further SEO on these keywords. Where can I see this?

I tried searching the GA4's "Explore" section, but it's not there. There are only queries for Google Ads:

[image]

Also, I tried this answer:

[How to do Google Analytics conversion/event tracking from organic keywords?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98443/how-to-do-google-analytics-conversion-event-tracking-from-organic-keywords)

It shows transactions per landing pages but not per search queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are exporting GA4 to BigQuery you can run a query that creates a table that tracks sessions.

That table can be used to build a Looker Studio report that focuses on GA4 sessions initiated by organic search, what their landing page was, and if they converted.

This data can be blended with the GSC data to find out the queries related to those landing pages.

You can't match a query to a session and therefore know which converted, but you can share the conversion value with all the queries for the landing page on that day. And get a rough idea of which queries are the most valuable.

I wrote an article called "Google Search Console + GA4 to BigQuery for a Looker Studio Report" about an example report I built that does this. The last tab in the report connects queries to revenue. You should be able to find it on Google.