# How to automate the identification of which organic keywords are generating leads?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

It seems [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98743/5026) is a solution to identifying which organic keywords are generating leads:

> Go to Search Traffic > Search Analytics, drill down into a specific
> keyword, then click the "Pages" radio button above the graph. You'll
> then be able to see what pages absorbed what amount of search traffic.
>
> To tie this to ROI, do a landing page drilldown under the Behavior >
> Site Content section of GA. If you look at the same page on the same
> date that you have set in Search Console and set your segment to just
> organic search traffic, you can look at revenue generated on that day,
> divide it by organic search sessions, and get a per-session value.
> This value is super useful for making business decisions (like a mini
> LTV).

It would be helpful to automate this process.

The answer above was from 2016, before Google Analytics 4.

Would Google Analytics 4 or Big Query help automate this process?

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Google's Looker Studio (formerly DataStudio):

https://lookerstudio.google.com/

It is a free app by **Google**, that allows you to connect to your **Google Search Console** data (and many others) to create dashboards.

You can create multiple views to suit your needs. For example to see which queries are driving visitors, how are they performing overtime, or compare how many visitors were brought by that query the last X days vs the previous ones.